# Subtracting two timestamps in bash script

Tags: bash, shell, date, math, timestamp

I have a file that contains a set of Timestamps in format of `H:M:S.MS`, I can read and print all of the saved Timestamps but when I do some arithmetic operation like Subtract (say `Timestamp2 - Timestamp1`) it doesn't give me the answer, I do not have experience work with bash script programming.

Any suggestions, recommendations will be much appreciated.

Here is the [screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vomda.png) of my problem.

Here is an example :

```
Start Time = 17:53:01.166721
End Time = 17:53:01.369787
```

The expected result for `End Time - Start Time` is either `0:00:0.203066` or `0.203066`.

Comment: How are your timestamps obtained? maybe we're having an XY problem here: are you trying to time a process?

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Do you have access to GNU date?

Comment: We are actually recording the time of the icmp packet (Send and Receive time) between two hosts. The obtained time is my local machine time . geniourf_gniourf

Comment: That doesn't tell _how_ you obtained the time stamps. Please show the (relevant part of the) code you're using.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to process the date using simple command line tools, you need to convert the timestamps into some easy-to-deal-with format, like epoch-based.

You can do this with the `date` command, which you can wrap in a function like so:

```
timestamp() { 
    date '+%s%N' --date="$1"
}
# timestamp '2020-01-01 12:20:45.12345' => 1577899245123450000
```

Then you can subtract them directly:

```
echo $(( $(timestamp "$etime") - $(timestamp "$stime") ))
```

---

Note that the `%N` format specifier (nanoseconds) is a GNU extension and is not handled in the default macOS `date` command. Either (a) `brew install coreutils` and use `gdate` in the function above or (b) use this alternative function on macOS (but note it lacks support for sub-second measurements):

```bash
timestamp() {
    local format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'     # set to whatever format is used
    date -j -f "$format" "$1" '+%s'
}
# timestamp '2020-01-01 12:20:45' => 1577899245
```

Comment: This works well even for input format that includes the date, e.g. `2020-01-10 19:00:22,968`

Comment: You probably want to divide by 1_000_000_000 to get back from nanoseconds to seconds.

Answer (score 5):

If you need to use bash, you need to convert the timestamp into an integer value:

```
$ time="12:34:56.789"
$ IFS=":." read -r h m s ms <<<"$time"
$ echo $h $m $s $ms
12 34 56 789
$ milliseconds=$(( (h*3600 + m*60 + s)*1000 + ms ))
$ echo $milliseconds
45296789
```

Then you can subtract to get a number of milliseconds representing the diff.

Convert to seconds with some arithmetic and string construction:

```
$ seconds="$((milliseconds / 1000)).$((milliseconds % 1000))"
$ echo $seconds
45296.789
```

---

To address gniourf_gniourf's valid point (in a clunky way):

```
$ time="12:34:56.7"
$ IFS=":." read -r h m s ms <<<"$time"
$ ms="${ms}000"; ms=${ms:0:3}
$ echo $h $m $s $ms
12 34 56 700
# .......^^^
```

---

Also, strings that are invalid octal numbers like "08" and "09" will throw errors in bash arithmetic, so explicitly declare they are base 10

```
milliseconds=$(( (10#$h*3600 + 10#$m*60 + 10#$s)*1000 + 10#$ms ))
```

Comment: This only works if there are 3 digits after the decimal period.

Comment: Doesn't this line `milliseconds=$(( (h*3600 + m*60 + s)*1000 + ms ))` need `"$"` on the  `h m s ms` values?

Comment: No, as documented in [Shell Arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Arithmetic) => "Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax."

Comment: This is subtle brilliance, thanks for sharing, helped me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your variables are integers, you need to enclose your calculation in an arithmetic evaluation for that to work.

```
echo $(( VAR1 - VAR2 ))
```

Or, if you want to assign the value :

```
VAR3=$(( VAR1 - VAR2 ))
```

Comment: You don't need the $ symbol for variables within the (()) context.